# phpstorm autosugestion for object from variable

Tags: php

I have class `Load` where I have method `model` to load model.
Method model will require file and create initiate object with name.

so output will be

```
require_once 'path_to_file/modelname.php';
$model = new Modelname_Model();
```

Usage:

```
<?php

$m = $this->load->model('test');

$m->__here_should_be_autosugestion_for_model__
```

How can I setup or edit code to phpstorm give me autosugestions for methods of object returned from variable?

Here is `Load` class

```
class Load
{

    /**
     * Load model by name
     * @param $name name of model
     * @return object
     */
    public function model($name)
    {
        if (!class_exists($name . '_Model')) {
            require_once APP_DIR . '/models/' . strtolower($name) . '.php';
        }
        $model_name = ucfirst($name) . '_Model';
        $model = new $model_name;
        return $model;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at autoloading [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) or even better [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and just create a new model `new Test_Model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way i know is to do it by using inline type comment

```
/**
 * @var Test_Model $m
 */
$m = $this->load->model('test');

$m->__here_should_be_autosugestion_for_model__
```

Comment: `/** @var Test_Model  $m */` But im not sure if the `$m` part is needed